# In App Purchase Feature: Iphone

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am having an in-app feature where user can upgrade the existing app to pro-version which will provide extra features. I want to publish the first basic version to app store, this version will have options to upgrade it to pro-version and messages will appear if user try to access features that is pro-only. Now my situtation is that i don't have pro-version app ready but want to publish basic version, So will apple reject my app because of this ? I mean i don't have pro-version available but i am providing upgrade (in-app purchase) option in basic version app. So when user selects upgrade option from basic version and only message will appear saying "Pro-version coming soon" (just as example).

Will apple reject my app ? or i am able to publish basic version and publish pro-version later on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of being reject are very very great. Since you have an option for people to buy something that is not yet available.Apple will see this a misleading and will probably reject your app.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. What do you suggest for my situation ? Should i remove special feature from first basic version, then when my pro-version is ready then i'l publish another update of basic version with special feature so user will have to buy/upgrade to access special feature ? So also i have to make sure that before publishing new update of basic version, pro-version is already published and available at app store. Right ?

Comment: Ya that sounds about write. But if you plan to use an InApp purchase then you can't link to the Pro version. The basic and pro version should be the same app, where if the user paid for the pro version the restrictions of the basic version are just lifted. This will work better then two different versions of the app.

Comment: Ok. I got it. So version 1.1 of app will have all special feature but locked and will be unlocked when in-app purchase is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely get rejected by Apple. You should read the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) before you submit any app to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your app will be most likely rejected if you do not provide the possibility to upgrade within your app. I had an app rejected for this same reason. And the tips thas I was given by Apple was to remove the 'special feature' button, or to propose the 'special feature' to purchase in-app.

Answer (score 0):

No, for the In-App purchase you will have to create first the Pro-Version and this Pro-Version upload first. If this your Pro-Version will approve then you will upload your Basic App to approve.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it is gonna be rejected.
check out the appstore guidelines. There should be no button/etc disabled or showing that something/some feature is coming soon. And you are getting money to tell this from the user.
That's dangerous.
just release the app without in app purchase initially, and as you get the pro features good and going, upload the next version of your app.